# How to kill the focus of Microsoft Word™ document window?

Tags: delphi, vba, com, ole

I'm developing a Word addin in Delphi, on a task pane I put a Virtual treeview, in the OnFocus event of the Virtual Treeview I call Word to insert a file into the current Word document via method ActiveDocument.Range.InsertFile,  but this operation will put the input focus back to the Word document window, so finally in this event handler I call TreeView.SetFocus to set the focus back to the treeview, this works except that the Word document window still has a unblinking caret shown.

I tried sending the WM_KILLFOCUS windows message to the handle of the Word document window but no luck. Any hints? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to call Application.BringToFront or Application.MainForm.BringToFront.

Comment: Hi The_Fox,
Thanks, both these two ways do not solve the probolem, maybe because the form is embedded in the Word main window. And the Application.MainForm property is nil.

Comment: Try to call BringToFront on your form containing the TreeView.